# Should I have A Single Table or Multiple Tables for MySql Database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to mysql and a self-taught. I am building a web site for advertising automobiles by users (doing this to get my hands-on the basics of the web development). Basically the sellers can post their vehicles in the site and buyers can view the ads and make a deal with the sellers.

I am setting up a mysql data base to store details of the automobiles which are fed by the sellers. 
The layout of the database is as follows;

'vehicles' sql table structure

[image: 'vehicles' sql table structure]

where, user_id is the primary key and auto increments as the sellers store their data in the data base. Please note that the table is *just a basic version of the actual table* *(to give an idea of the layout)*. The actual table has around **200 columns**. Then the queries are run like follows *(please note shows a basic version of the real query)*;

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vehicles 
    WHERE $sale_or_rent = 1 
        AND $vehicle_type = 1 
        AND $make = 1 
        AND price>= $price 
        AND year>= $year 
        AND mileage>= $mileage 
    ORDER BY price ASC 
    LIMIT 0,100");
```

In the PHP code before the query, depending on the buyer's inputs to filter the results, the variables are set using SWITCH statements like;

```
$sale_or_rent = "for_sale" OR "for_rent" //depending on the input

$vehicle_type = "car" OR "pickup"
```

and so on for all the variables in the query `SELECT` statement.

So, my question is, is this way of having ONE TABLE for tackling the problem for a web site like this efficient (if the web site is intended for a heavy traffic usage)?

Or do I need to go for Several Tables (say one for vehicle type, one for vehicle make etc.) and use the `JOIN`S to yield the final results for the queries ?

I have never developed such a web site before, and I highly appreciate your advices/ comments regarding this. I am more than thankful if you can elaborate your answers why I need to follow the suggesting path (pros/ cons of doing such). Please provide me some tips so that I can guide my self in the correct path when I develop a large scale web site in the future.

Comment: You should read about [Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/). So yes, you should have different tables for things like `brand` instead of adding more columns to your tables. Why? Say you want to add a new brand, you then only need to insert a new row into the `brand`-table instead of altering the table schema (like you currently would need). The `brand`-name would then also be a usable value in your result and not a column name. Read the link and do more research for more info about it.

Comment: You should also look into parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries using string interpolation (using php variables directly in your SQL string).

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply Magnus, got one question: so apart from difficulty in management of the DB (using one huge table like this), is there a performace issue  (like time taken) in a Single Table over multiple tables like you are suggesting?

Comment: As long as you have properly indexed your table and don't use `SELECT *` for each query (but rather define the columns you actually need), there shouldn't be a performance issue. But the negatives definitely outweighs the positives. If you, for example, want to show a list or drop down with all the car brands, you would need to hard code them into your application,which wouldn't make it very dynamic.

Comment: You should also make things like `for_sale` and `for_rent` into one table with a value that indicates the status. If you find yourself using PHP variables as column names, like `$sale_or_rent = 1`, then you more often than not should look into the architecture. I'm not saying it has to be wrong because of that. Sometimes you need to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much Magnus, going through the normalization lessons. Well, I got columns holding the status for like for_sale and for_rent (if for example a vehicle is for sale, then the corresponding row has 1 for the column of for_sale, and for_rent will be null for it). And the corresponding PHP variables are passed with the corresponding column names. For example for a query finding a selling car, the PHP variable of $sale_or_rent is passed a value of "for_sale"which is the corresponding column name for a selling car. contd to next comment.....

Comment: contd from previous...... And then in the query, query search for the results in the column of for_sale where it holds the value of '1'. The nulls will be ignored. Any problem you see in here performance wise (instead of the dynamic updatability and ease of management of the db) ?